# VBA LOOP in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, vba, loops

I was trying to write a VBA to run a query assigned to MySQL only when the `HCR_DM.HCR_DM_FACT` table is fully loaded. I'm using the count of distinct source in that table to decide if it is fully loaded.

When I was running the Macro below, I got an error message for the Do While line, saying that `Object doesn't support this property or method.`

I'm quite new to VBA, and I couldn't figure out what need to be adjusted. Can some one help me with this?

Thanks!

```vb
Const CNSTR = "Provider = OraOLEDB.Oracle; Data Source =CSDPRO; ODBC;DRIVER={Oracle ODBC Driver};SERVER=CSDPRO;User ID=HCR_SANDBOX;password=******"

Sub FillWithSQLData(strSQL As String, wkSht As String)
' Given a SQL query and worksheet, fills the worksheet with a data dump of the SQL query results

' Define variables
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim sql_count As String



' Set variables
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


' Connect to SQL Server
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = CNSTR
        .Open
    End With

' Query SQL Server and return results as a data dump in cell A2 of the specified worksheet
    With rs
        .ActiveConnection = cn

        sql_count = "select count( distinct  a.src_table) from hcr_dm.hcr_dm_fact a"

        Set rf = cn.Execute(sql_count)
        Do While rf.Fields.Value = 8

        .Open strSQL

        Loop

        Worksheets(wkSht).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

        .Close
    End With

' Close connection
    cn.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set Conn = Nothing

End Sub




Sub Refresh()

  ' Define SQL query
  Dim mySQL As String
  mySQL = "select a.oracle_fin_company_id || ' - ' || a.oracle_fin_company_desc as COMPANY " & _
            "From hcr_dm.legal_entity_summary a " & _
            "where a.Company_Header = 'Filed'"

  ' Choose worksheet where results should be displayed
  Dim myWkSht As String
  myWkSht = "Sheet1"

  ' Call connection sub
  Call FillWithSQLData(mySQL, myWkSht)

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like a little mess. You are talking about MySQL, in your ConnectionString you use `OraOLEDB.Oracle` and `DRIVER={Oracle ODBC Driver}`. For proper ConnectionString please check [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) or [Connection Strings](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=81)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not selecting a field.  The lines

```
Set rf = cn.Execute(sql_count)
Do While rf.Fields.Value = 8
```

Should probably be

```
Set rs = cn.Execute(sql_count)
Do While rs.Fields(0).Value = 8
```

Also, note the typo in that you declared `rs` but you're filling `rf` with the Recordset. 
I recommend you use the `Option Explicit` statement to help find these.  You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278855(v=office.14).aspx).